# UpdraftPlus WordPress plugin is not working to store Backup in the Google Drive

Tags: wordpress, backup

I used [updraftplus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/updraftplus/) plugin for creating and storing the backup of everything in google drive. I have already linked my Google account with the plugin.

Inside WordPress, I can see the updraftplus is working perfectly. I can see some backups already created as per my desired schedule but I can't locate these backups in my google drive.

The logs generated by the plugin for the last backup is here: https://www.codepile.net/pile/VmrK6Oy7

Answer (score 0):

Goto Google Drive check folder whose name is UpdraftPlus. You can see all backup files. In WordPress Dashboard go to UpdraftPlus Backup Section see all backup lists.

[image: UpdraftPlus Backup list]

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. The folder name in the settings is *UpdraftPlus*. I'm using the free version and in the free version, this is the default google drive folder name. The free version is not allowing to change of the folder name.

In the below screenshot, you can also see I'm authenticated.

Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/_iDvKKMqmMTm

I can see all the backups created as per my desired schedule but backings are not going to GoogleDrive.

Comment: You need to authenticate with Google. Please click Sign in With Google and provide credentials. After Authenticated shows your name like the screenshot. 
screenshot link - https://prnt.sc/f81QlBbR4abp

Answer (score 0):

After switching many Google accounts, it starts working with all accounts.

For a while, I realized that it is only working with personal Google accounts, not with Guite accounts. But it is working now with Gsuite also